# Why has Blender created 250 disp_[number].exr files?

Tags: cache, .exr

I recently checked my cache files and found that Blender has somehow created 250 *.exr* files with an image I've never seen before. Has anyone an idea why Blender could have created exactly 250 files of this colorful image below?

[image: disp_250.exr]

Comment: Maybe this is result of baking Ocean modifier

Comment: You’re right, it looks that way.